# Finding the Domain of the function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$f(x)=  \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x^2-4x} $$

I want to find the domain of above function 
$$[-1,-\infty)\cup(4,\infty)$$
Just want to confirm is it true

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

You should have
$$
x-1>0
$$ *and*
$$
x^2-4x \neq0.
$$

Comment: I make some changes is it true now

Comment: @AmirShahzad The first condition $x>1$ means $(1,\infty)$, the second one $x(4-x)\neq 0$ means $x\neq0$ and $4-x\neq0$, finally we get $D=(1,4)\cup (4,\infty)$ to be the right domain.